# Displays Activity Indicator after Tab Bar pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Tab Bar with 5 items and 5 Views which attached to this items. I need to display Activity Indicator when I press on item and View is loading.How can I do it? I try to I tried to do what was written in similar 
issues on StackOverflow, but I could not get. Can someone explain and show an example of how to do it for a beginner like me? I would be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) for that. download project from github from given link just drag and drop mbprogreshud.h and .m file to your project.

then when you want to show activity indicator,

import `mbprogresshud.h` file and

```
 [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; //to show
```

when finish your task and want to hide activity indicator then,

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
});
```

you can refer that github link for more detail. it's have good information about how to use it also.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you! Now it looks easier for use. But I put [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES] to didSelectItem and don`t know where to put [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES]; My problem: if i put showHUDAddedTo to didSelectItem, Indicator appears after the load my View (i need it after i click on Tab and before, when the table is displayed on my View (View = TableView). Maybe I did something wrong with the loading my Table View :(

Comment: then show hud in viewdidload and hide when your tableview completely become visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"%@", item); 
}
```

Use this code in delegate and show activity in each click.
also can take help from below URL.

[iphone : How to display Activity Indicator on clicking Tab Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732135/iphone-how-to-display-activity-indicator-on-clicking-tab-bar?rq=1)

Comment: your links seems to in wrong context. here question is about `activityindicator` means loader which comes when some task is running and we want to block main thread untill completion. Your link have explanation of `networkactivityindicator` which is generally shown in `status ba`r when application communicate with remote resources via internet,wifi etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there here is My idea:

1- Implement UITabbarDelegate on the viewcontroller

```
UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>
```

2- Add some variable for the UITabBar control (and of course for the viewcontroller, view if you need it):

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITabBar *curTabBar;
@synthesize curTabBar
```

3- On the UITabBar delegate

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem)item
    {
 //First of all creat activity Indicator view if not create    
    if(self.activityIndicatorView == nil)
    {     

      //Create one activity indicator whatever you use, MBProgressHUD ,...
        UIActivityIndicatorView *oneAcIV = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    }

    //Add activity indicator
    [self.view insertSubview:self.activityIndicatorView belowSubview:self.curTabBar];//Or aboveSubview depending on the result you want


    //Create the new view

    self.NewView = ....
    //Add the new View below activty indicator
    [self.view insertSubview:self.NewView belowSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    }
```